# Mysql Data Query not working

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm trying to select the teams and username but show only teams from today's date.
The teams column is within the accumulatorbet column. Win is also an accumulatorbet column.

Here is the code:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT teams, members.username 
              FROM accumulatorbet 
              LEFT JOIN members ON accumulatorbet.userid = members.id
              WHERE win = 'yes' AND DATE('tu') = DATE(NOW()) ");
```

I'm joining with 'members' to find the username who has the specific team.

No rows are showing with this query, when there should be one row returned. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: why not run the sql from phpmyadmin and see what it says.

Comment: What's `DATE('tu')`? If `tu` is a column name you need to remove the quotes. Likely your problem.

Comment: where does that `teams` come from? really, better idea to have correct table alias... :)

Comment: tu is a datetime timestamp column. Teams column is from accumulatorbet

Comment: oh dear..(embarrassed face) it was the quotes!

Comment: As suggested by @Cfreak please remove single quote (') around tu and try to run your query...

Answer (score 0):

you are making `left join` , so it will show only the teams from the first table , because your `WHERE` clause cant be true.

instead your `where` clause can be like that

```
 WHERE win = 'yes' AND DATE(tu) = DATE(NOW()) ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT teams, m.username 
FROM accumulatorbet a
LEFT JOIN members m ON a.userid = m.id
WHERE win = 'yes' AND DATE(tu) = CURRENT_DATE();
```